# SQL Developer - Data Modeler extension is not displayed

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-sql-data-modeler

I installed SQL developer sqldeveloper-18.3.0.277.2354-no-jre.zip nd when I access Help -> About in the extensions tab I cannot see the oracle.datamodeler extension. I can find the jar file in the extracted files though in sqldeveloper/extensions
Is there aything I can do to make it work?

Comment: Do you see a Model tab when opening a table? Do you see Data Modeler on the file, view, or tools menus? If not, id extract SQLDev to a FRESH directory and say NO to importing previous settings